# What do you use instead of placeholder settings in SXA?

Tags: sxa, placeholders

I want to restrict which components can be used within a placeholder when using the Sitecore Experience Accelerator module. Normally, I'd use placeholder settings to do this, but it doesn't seem to work in SXA 1.1. Is there an alternative approach to limit what content editors can add to a placeholder? Is this a bug?

I've tried associating the placeholder setting at the page design and at the partial design level, but it doesn't work in either place -- I still get the full list of SXA renderings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Sitecore Experience Accelerator** uses a different approach for that.

You can define your access rights  for each rendering/group of renderings by changing the access rights to **Available Renderings** items.

To do it follow these steps

- Navigate to **Available Renderings** node (`/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Presentation/Available Renderings`)
- Pick item which represents a group of renderings you want to limit
- Assign security rights (for example set `Read` to `false` for certain group or user)

After that, when you log in with your user you will see that the Toolbox contains only available renderings (I set `Read` to `false` for all items under **Available Renderings**, except **Media** and **Page Content**)

[image]

This differs from standard `Allowed Controls` approach. Due to the nature of dynamic placehcolders, you can set renderings availability per site not per placeholder.

**EDIT:**

SXA 1.4 brings placeholders settings back!

Read more [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/set_placeholder_restrictions)

Comment: Not being able to limit availability by placeholder is a big drawback. We'd like to keep people from putting components in the wrong places.

Comment: @dthrasher I completely agree with you. This is something that should be implemented.